# I cannot instantly reconnect to ssh server after logout

Tags: ssh, centos5

I have a ssh server on an old CentOS 5 installation. I can connect to the server without any problems. However, if i disconnect from the server and want to login again after exiting the previous session, the server is not responding and i got a "connection timed out" error. After a while (must be between 1 and 5 minutes) i can login normally. If i then exit the session, the same timeout happens again.

From the network where the client resides, i can connect to other ssh servers without any problems, so i dont think, this is a firewall issue.

Any suggestions, where i can look for the problem?

I tried to login with key instead of password and i stopped the fail2ban service on the ssh server. Both without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

There is a iptables rule, which is limiting the connections per ip to one attempt per minute. I have whitelisted my ip and now there is no delay when reconnecting.